# Why pages not blocked by robots.txt are not indexing?

Tags: google, google-search-console, robots.txt, google-index

In my google search console's coverage section, the diagram tells that there are 114 excluded pages. It says 40 of them is blocked by robots.txt and 22 of them is excluded by 'noindex' tab, but I didn't exclude or blocked any of them. Even when I test them with google robots.txt tester it says the links are allowed and some of these URLs are those ones that I removed from my site along time ago before I launch the site and allowing bots to crawl.
This is my website: e-anatomy.ir
[image]

Comment: Dear Stephan, in the question you pointed he asked why google isn't indexing my content but my question is why google doesn't index my content and says its because of the robots.txt and I'm sure it isn't, because the robots.txt tester says these pages allow bots to crawl!

Comment: No answers for my comment?